# When using the fstream is all the file's content loaded into memory?

Tags: c++, file-io

My point is, when opening a file with fstream::open all the file's content is loaded into memory? When you are reading from or writing to a file you are actually doing these operations in memory or there's a lot of disk access being made?

Comment: Nothing is loaded into memory when you open the file. A buffer-load is read when you do a read. When you write, you write to a buffer which is autoflushed when full or when you close.

Comment: The title of the question is not quite the same as the body text.  Is it about the way fstreams are read/written ?  or is it about the effect of open() ?

Comment: There's no answer that applies to everything.  Nothing is stopping me from writing a driver that pre-loads an entire file into RAM when you open it.

Comment: @Christophe is about both. You're right when you talk about the title and the body text. Sorry.

Comment: @indiv you mean the way the operations of fstream are performed depends on the driver or whatever it is reading from?

Comment: @eap: Yes he did mean that. But no usual driver will do that.

Comment: @indiv The question is specifically about the behaviour of `fstream`, not drivers.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the entire contents of the file are not read into memory when the file is opened.

For example, if this were the case, 1 GB files would be automatically loaded into memory.  This would take a while.  Also, your platform would need 1GB of available memory.

It may also be a waste.  If you only want the first text line or the first 64 bytes, reading in the 1GB file would be a waste of time and memory in this case.

There may be some buffering happening.  For example, the driver may read the directory table from the hard drive and store into memory.

Let's take another case, if I want to open a file for writing, does it make sense to read the entire file into memory?

Most likely, the drivers do not read entire files into memory when they are opened.  You need to tell the driver to read and where to put the data.

Answer (score 1):

The general design of the iostream library has two types of io objects; the stream objects themselves, and stream buffer objects.  The stream objects worry mainly about formatting; things like converting longs to hex,  being told to output hex, and so on; but they really don't care much about where they are writing.   The stream buffers ignore the formatting aspects and are concerned with interacting with some device--a file,  a string, a console,  etc.   The stream objects simply have pointers to the appropriate stream buffer objects and defer to them for the actual io.  In the case of fstream objects, the stream buffer object being used is filebuf (a specialization of basic_filebuf for char streams).

The entire design of the buffered objects is centered around the notion of reading from or writing to buffers and hooking just in time read and write events to empty buffers, though they can also behave in an unbuffered manner.  These buffers are the ones defined by C++ proper; if used by your implementation, they have nothing to do with total file sizes. If they hold the entire file, it would simply be because the file fits inside the buffer length they chose.